# Troubles with Unicode string encoding in Android

Tags: android, string, unicode, encoding

I get strings in different encodings (ID3 tags).
I use e.g. `new String( bytes, "UTF-16LE" )` to decode them.
On my device (Motorola Milestone) and in the emulator, this works fine.
But some users complained they get results like "T i t l e   n a m e".
I've tried the Sun codepage names instead (e.g. "UnicodeBigUnmarked"), with the same result - works for me, not for the user. (Reported and tested on Samsung Galaxy, but according to Market comments, this doesn't seem to be the only device...)
Is there some alternative that works on all devices, like other codepage names or a convertion class? Or is it a bug in the runtime environment I can't work around?

Comment: What happens if you specify "UTF-16"?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know whether they have the Charset on their device, try getting them to download "Dalvik Explorer" from the Market, and check to see that the ones you need are actually available.

(do you know their ID3 tags are valid? do you know your parser is choosing the right encoding? i wrote my own ID3 tag parser because i couldn't find one that was correct.)