# What characters are available on Android?

Tags: java, android, unicode, fonts, character

I'd like to display some special Unicode characters in my Android app. These characters are not listed on droidfonts.com but they are displayed correctly on the emulator and on my phone, but want to be sure if all Android platforms will support them. Is it documented somewhere? Thanks!

EDIT

I'm looking for a method like [canDisplay](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplay%28char%29).

Comment: well, if they display on your phone, then i would assume they would display on any other, right?

Comment: so what we need is an app that tries to display all code pages, for developers to look which ones can be used, right?

Answer (score 8):

Android Support Unicode completely, but you need a `Unicode font` to display your characters as I know The `Droid Sans font`, from Android framework, contains the unicode 
character. but if you have are going to use from Unicode 6.0 new glyphs (like New Indian Roop)  you have to use a font that supports it.

This article may help you : http://groups.google.com/group/android-framework/browse_thread/thread/73586caa2e06e052?pli=1 .

Also you can check this for more information : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5925

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately different phones can have different versions of the standard system font (Droid Sans) that include or don't include certain Unicode glyphs. See: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5925

The only sure-fire solution is to include your own custom font that you know contains all the glyphs you need in your app. The next best thing is to use only a small subset of Unicode: US, European, Japanese, and Korean glyphs are a pretty safe bet in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what characters specifically you're referring to. It would be easier to give a better answer knowing  but it appears not all are supported. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5925

Also, it appears to be device specific. [Troubles with Unicode string encoding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147170/troubles-with-unicode-string-encoding-in-android)

this seems to answer your question [Are all the Unicode characters supported on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766912/are-all-the-unicode-characters-supported-on-android)

Comment: These links say that some characters may or may not be present, but I'd like to know if there is a list of supported characters, or else, how I can test if a specific character is present on a specific platform. (In my example, if not present, I would replace ♯ by #)

Answer (score 0):

I think an easy way to accomplish this is to include the desired font that supports the characters with your application, see below for a tutorial:

"Using Custom Fonts on Android"

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/04/using-custom-fonts-on-android.html

Regards

Ziteng Chen

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what we need is an app that tries to display all code pages, for developers to look which ones can be used, right? I found this one:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chudanqing.s1001fonts