# Displaying the unicode characters with real devices and emulators

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fonts, unicode-literals

Some unicode characers don't display on real devices and emulators but stay displaying within Android Studio design mode. For example,
**In design mode:**
[image]

but the emulator (as well as real device) shows nothing:
[image]

So, why this is it? And, what should I do to gain the expected result?

**UPD:**
As one of perheps solution I tryied to use [androidx.emoji2:emoji2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji2#impact-automatic-config)  library. And this helped me bit. But this is poor efficiency as for me. Because using proposed bundle upsize my app from 1.5Mb up to 22Mb. Using the downloadable font provider may solve this, but as it says:

> *"The initializer creates a background thread to load the emoji font, and font download may take up to 10 seconds before timing out. After
> the font is downloaded, it takes approximately 150 milliseconds on a
> background thread to initialize EmojiCompat."*

So, although I wanted to use unicode benifits to avoid using additional graphic resources, but now I have no another idea as to use vector resources for my aim.

**If anyone had other experiences in this area, please, share here.**

Comment: It depends on the device. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449321/what-characters-are-available-on-android

Comment: I tried to use custom font (https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Download/BabelStoneRoman.ttf) but faced with error: "error: string to large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE'"

Comment: One more thing, the BabelStoneRoman font pointed out above works fine. That was my fault regarding a large font size that encourage an error "Font size too large to fit in cache", and the error pointed above was being the result of this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a font issue. The font used by Android studio may not supports that character while the android device, you will need to embed a font which support that character.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="\u270c"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This code worked for me and below one was the result in emulator `PIXEL 5 API 32`
[image]

Also, it seems to be device specific. [Troubles with Unicode string encoding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588965/how-to-use-custom-font-in-a-project-written-in-android-studio/27588966#27588966)